# TFS 2013 Build: Type is not defined error

Tags: vb.net, tfs, tfsbuild

We are setting our new TFS server to do our builds. All applications build except for one. The exact errors are here: 
Image Link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XDnkYviZjKU0lCVmFEQjF6Q1E/edit?usp=sharing

The project is named QAVB. It has a reference to another project named tlbQA_DB. In tlbQA_DB is a class named tlbQA_Manager.vb. The properties of this file are: Build Action - Compile & Do not copy to output directory. 

The application will build and can be built and ran locally. The project is set to build in x86 and signed with a key file, which is included in the project. 

Image of  project structure: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XDnkYviZjKTzYzb25BNFk2NmM/edit?usp=sharing

Why does TFS build process say this class is not defined?

Comment: QAVB is Web Site or a Web App project?

Comment: I can't see your images.

Comment: Giulio - QAVB is a VB WebApplication.
Dave - I'm not sure why. They are hosted on google drive.